# Salesforce - Lightning Database with lazyload and Sorting

Tags: lightning, datatable, sort, lazy-loading

How can we use lightning data table lazy load functionality with sorting of columns?

As Lazy load only will bring certain no of records at a time then sorting actually is working on those set of records and not total data.

Please suggest any examples if we have

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch all the records before lazy loading from apex controller into to controller.js
2. store the data in a global variable or attribute : let’s say “initalrecords”
3. Try using the records in “initalrecords” to lazyload or sort it..